# mysql Extraction base champ

Tags: mysql

That one day I stuck on a query. If anyone see the error it would be nice

My aim to isolate and remind each field value.

my Base

```
id  date    BudCaLicFrance  BudQteLicFrance CaLicFrance QteLicFrance    BudCaLicInter   BudQteLicInter  CaLicInter  QteLicInter BudCaDirFrance  BudQteDirFrance CaDirFrance QteDirFrance    BudCaDirInter   BudQteDirInter  CaDirInter  QtedirInter BudCaGdcptFrance    BudQteGdcptFrance   CaGdcptFrance   QteGdcptFrance  BudCaGdcptInter BudQteGdcptInter    CaGdcptInter    QteGdcptInter   AvoirCaLicFrance    AvoirQteLicFrance   AvoirCaDirFrance    AvoirQteDirFrance   FacCaLicFrance  FacQteLicFrance FacCaDirFrance  FacQteDirFrance
1   01/08/2014  37334,04545 1023,765639 18995,7 593 15316,33916 988,0233931 1485    38  16884,36364 3528,466499 20717,49    4594    3746,636364 896,8325613 0   0   19545,45455     0   0   1294,409091     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   04/08/2014  37334,04545 1023,765639 13523,6 632 15316,33916 988,0233931 2729,6  86  16884,36364 3528,466499 22358,65    6024    3746,636364 896,8325613 720,7   57  19545,45455     0   0   1294,409091     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   05/08/2014  37334,04545 1023,765639 17186,71    679 15316,33916 988,0233931 4468    253 16884,36364 3528,466499 21318,1 5366    3746,636364 896,8325613 2825,6  323 19545,45455     1556    228 1294,409091     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

My Request: Row is the date that is dynamic, I check to replace it with the value in hard, I have the same result

```
$result10 = mysql_query("SELECT CaLicFrance FROM Ca WHERE date In ('$row[1]', '$row[2]', '$row[3]', '$row[4]', '$row[5]', '$row[6]', '$row[7]', '$row[8]', '$row[9]', '$row[10]', '$row[11]', '$row[12]', '$row[13]', '$row[14]', '$row[15]', '$row[16]', '$row[17]', '$row[18]', '$row[19]', '$row[20]', '$row[21]', '$row[22]')" );  
IF (!$result10) {
   echo 'Impossible d\'exécuter la requête : ' . mysql_error();
   exit;
}
$row10 = mysql_fetch_row($result10);

 echo $row10[0]; 
 echo $row10[1];
```

My goal is to get in  `echo $row10 [0];`  the first value (18995.7) then `echo $row10 [1];`  The second (13,523.6) ... ect. 
With my query only the first value is displayed. the `echo $row10 [1];` does not work. 
I feel that my query does not output the values ​​2 and 3, while direct sql, I have 3 values ​​that appears.

Thank you to you for help

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_fetch_row()** return  **one row** only, you can use **mysql_fetch_assoc()**

Try below code:

```
$result10 = mysql_query("SELECT CaLicFrance FROM Ca WHERE date In ('$row[1]', '$row[2]', '$row[3]', '$row[4]', '$row[5]', '$row[6]', '$row[7]', '$row[8]', '$row[9]', '$row[10]', '$row[11]', '$row[12]', '$row[13]', '$row[14]', '$row[15]', '$row[16]', '$row[17]', '$row[18]', '$row[19]', '$row[20]', '$row[21]', '$row[22]')" );  
IF (!$result10) {
   echo 'Impossible d\'exécuter la requête : ' . mysql_error();
   exit;
}
while($row10 = mysql_fetch_array($result10))
{
 echo $row10[0]; 
 echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the `mysql_fetch_XXX` functions just returns one row at a time. You need to call it in a loop:

```
while ($row10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result10)) {
    echo $row10['CaLicFrance'];
}
```